# How do you access images in the public folder from a css file while using react-router-dom?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've been working on a login program to practice my Python, MongoDB, and CSS.

I am using react-router-dom to have the URL change whenever the user goes to another page while keeping redux (I mean, that's kind of the point of it). However, I'm also using CSS (located in the src folder, each put in a styles.css file next to the component it's for), and I want to include a background image in the CSS with a linear gradient of a low opacity over it. My CSS code looks like this:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(var(--color-example-1), .8), rgba(var(--color-example-2), .8)), url(/images/example-image.png);
```

And my App.js file looks like this:

```
// ABSOLUTES
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

// PAGES
import ChangePasswordPage from './pages/ChangePasswordPage';
import ForgotPasswordPage from './pages/ForgotPasswordPage';
import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage';
import SignedInPage from './pages/SignedInPage';
import SignUpPage from './pages/SignUpPage';

// VARIABLES
import { history } from './variables';

// STYLES
import './styles.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Router history={history}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/login'>
              <LoginPage />
            </Route>

            <Route exact path='/signup'>
              <SignUpPage />
            </Route>

            <Route exact path='/'>
              <SignedInPage />
            </Route>

            <Route exact path='/forgotpassword'>
              <ForgotPasswordPage />
            </Route>

            <Route exact path='/changepassword'>
              <ChangePasswordPage />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The problem is that, instead of getting the image from the public folder, it gets App.js even though it doesn't match any of the path parameters. Is there any way to access the public folder instead of react-router-dom?

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding this correctly, it boils down to the file path then. I'm assuming your file structure is similar to a basic create-react-app as below:

```
main folder
-- public folder
----> images folder
------>> example-image.png
-- src folder
----> App.js
----> styles.css
```

In that case, instead of referencing

> /images/example-image.png

which is pulling from the same directory, you want to go back 2 hierarchical levels from the styles.css file to the main folder, and then go down the hierarchy into the public folder for your image. So you will be going from styles.css -> src folder -> main folder -> public folder -> images folder -> your image.

> ../../public/images/example-image.png

"../" refers to moving up/back one level in the hierarchy. "./" or "/" refers to the current level. Does this help with your problem?

Comment: That doesn't work because (1) relative references cause in error in CSS files (at least, in React they do; I don't know about in plain HTML) and (2) you can't reference the public folder from the src folder; it has something to do with how they're rendered onto the page.

Comment: I see, does this thread help? They seem to have tried to do the same thing as you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57162841/use-images-in-css-files-with-reactjs

Comment: I think I could use those solutions, but they involve a lot of extra code; I'd rather use a simpler solution.