# How to set the background image in react js using external css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

### I am trying to set the image in the background of the container via external css , but it says modules not found ,what is the correct path I should give in background-image....

---

```
     import React from 'react'
import './Login.css'
const Login = () => {
    return (
        <>
        <div className="container-fluid img-wrapper bg-danger">
        </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default Login
```

---

```
  *{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
     .img-wrapper{
        background-image:url(../public/login-bg.png);
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height:100vh;
    }
```

Comment: Where is your `img-wrapper` element? There isn't any element that matches with that class

Comment: Sorry for that,yeah img-wrapper element is in the main div having class container-fluid, I was trying to make changes so mistakenly I didnot write here

Comment: Did you try to add `width` to your div as well?

Comment: @orotype yes I tried that too but the mistake is in path cause when I am trying to insert online image  it is working fine

Comment: Sorry bro, but can't help you without more information about your directory organization and other files

Comment: @AngeloSchulerPiletti I have folder directory like this public/images/login-bg.png

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are facing the same issue as in this question:
[Use images in CSS files with ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57162841/use-images-in-css-files-with-reactjs)

You can add the photo to your public folder, since the server is served there. As provided in this Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-turing-gsnr3?file=/src/styles.css